# PersistenceQuery and Akka-Http zombie stream

Tags: akka-http, akka-persistence

Im atempting to stream the PersistenceQuery result with akka-http as SSE but it seems like when the http connection is closed from the client the PersistenceQuery stream is still hitting the event backend periodically.

```
// Http part
complete {
   source(id)
        .map(e => e.event) // other transformations
        .map(e => ServerSentEvent(m.toString))
        .keepAlive(4 seconds, () => ServerSentEvent.heartbeat)
}

// source
def source(id: UUID)(implicit system: ActorSystem, materializer: ActorMaterializer)= {
    import system.dispatcher

    val journalQuery = PersistenceQuery(system).readJournalFor[CassandraReadJournal](CassandraReadJournal.Identifier)

    val futureSrcGraph:  RunnableGraph[Future[Source[EventEnvelope, NotUsed]]] =
      journalQuery.currentEventsByPersistenceId(id.toString, 0, Long.MaxValue)
        .map(_.sequenceNr)
        .toMat(Sink.last)(Keep.right)
        .mapMaterializedValue(fs => fs.recoverWith {
          case _ => Future { 0L } // assume we start at 1
        }.map(s => journalQuery.eventsByPersistenceId(id.toString, s + 1, Long.MaxValue)))

    Source.fromFutureSource(futureSrcGraph.run())
```

So this basically works the only problem is that the stream is never finished or so it seems. I have tried it with both CassandraReadJournal and LevelDb

Example of the log output:

```
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:16.774] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query from seqNr [6] in partition [0]
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:16.790] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query took [15] ms (empty)
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:16.790] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query from seqNr [6] in partition [1]
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:16.796] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query took [5] ms (empty)
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:19.768] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query from seqNr [6] in partition [0]
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:19.784] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query took [15] ms (empty)
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:19.784] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query from seqNr [6] in partition [1]
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:19.790] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query took [6] ms (empty)
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:22.765] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query from seqNr [6] in partition [0]
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:22.772] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query took [6] ms (empty)
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:22.772] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query from seqNr [6] in partition [1]
[DEBUG] [06/18/2018 10:52:22.790] [sys-cassandra-plugin-default-dispatcher-17] [EventsByPersistenceIdStage(akka://sys)] EventsByPersistenceId [c6031a8a-db71-4dcb-9d4f-f140faa2f4c4] Query took [17] ms (empty)
```

And it keeps going for ever.

I have also tried omitting the Source.fromFutureSource and just running journalQuery.eventsByPersistenceId with the same results.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The here were that my corporat proxy never drops the connection to the server even when the client closes the connection.